# Query works in SQL Server, trying to replicate in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case, wildcard

I have a query that works as intended in SQL Server, but when I try to replicate it in Oracle, it doesn't work.

- In SQL Server, it returns `Column1` with 5 characters.
- In Oracle, it is returning the original values.

Oracle syntax isn't my strong point, how can I get this to work, any suggestions would be appreciated

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '__-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('000', (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 2)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '___-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('00', (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 3)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '_______-_____' 
            THEN (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 3, 5))
        ELSE Column1 
    END AS NewColumn
FROM 
    schema.table1
```

Here it is again with a CTE so you can see it works as intended in SQL Server:

```
WITH cte_test AS 
(
    SELECT '12-3456' AS Column1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '78-9101'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1234567-89101'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-4321'
)
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '__-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('000', (SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 2)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '___-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('00', (SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 3)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '_______-_____' 
            THEN (SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 3, 5))
        ELSE Column1
    END AS NewColumn
FROM 
    cte_test
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing would help.  What is the data type of `column1`?

Comment: If I use the CTE from your SQL Server test and your Oracle `select`, it seems to work for me-- here's my fiddle showing it doing what you appear to want https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52c63409c04cb187554d9edde330057f  Oracle has a `trim` function so it doesn't make sense in this case to do `ltrim(rtrim())` but that's not causing a problem

Comment: Are you sure that the data in the actual table is what you think it is?  If there was some problem in the data migration and there are leading/ trailing spaces or control characters in `Column1`, that could explain why the `like` expression isn't matching for you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am unable to provide sample data beyond the test data in the CTE. The CONCAT is padding the left side with 0's to reach 5 characters.
 Column1 datatype is CHAR (20)

It is all explained it the original post

In SQL Server, it returns Column1 with 5 characters. -- (intended function)
In Oracle, it is returning the original values. -- (not intended function)

Comment: @JustinCave yes, I have the same exact table mirrored in  Oracle and in a MSSQL environment. It works in MSSQL but not Oracle. RTRIM/LTRIM would deal with any leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Are you looking at the fiddle I posted?  Is the fiddle returning the results you want?  You aren't trimming the result before doing the `like` so if there are leading or trailing spaces (in either the Oracle or the SQL Server version), the `like` patterns won't match and you'd just return the `Column1` value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you've declared the column in the Oracle table as `char(20)`.  `char(20)` is a fixed width data type so it will always be space padded out to 20 characters.  Given your sample data, that wastes space and means that neither of your `like` clauses are going to match the sample data because of the trailing spaces.  You really want to declare the column in the table as `varchar2(20)` so that it is not blank padded.

If you just take the CTE from your SQL Server example and use it with your Oracle code, the query returns what you want because Oracle treats the column in the CTE as a `varchar2`

```
WITH cte_test AS 
(
    SELECT '12-3456' AS Column1 from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '78-9101' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1234567-89101' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-4321' from dual
)
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '__-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('000', (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 2)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '___-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('00', (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 3)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '_______-_____' 
            THEN (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 3, 5))
        ELSE Column1 
    END AS NewColumn
FROM cte_test
```

If you create the table as a `char(20)` and insert the data, it gets space padded so the `like` statements don't do what you want

```
create table char_test( column1 char(20) );

insert into char_test
WITH cte_test AS 
(
    SELECT '12-3456' AS Column1 from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '78-9101' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1234567-89101' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-4321' from dual
    )
    select * from cte_test;

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '__-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('000', (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 2)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '___-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('00', (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 1, 3)))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '_______-_____' 
            THEN (SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(Column1)), 3, 5))
        ELSE Column1 
    END AS NewColumn
FROM char_test
```

You can work around that by trimming `Column1` before doing the `like`

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN trim(Column1) LIKE '__-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('000', (SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 2)))
        WHEN trim(Column1) LIKE '___-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('00', (SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 3)))
        WHEN trim(Column1) LIKE '_______-_____' 
            THEN (SUBSTR(Column1, 3, 5))
        ELSE Column1 
    END AS NewColumn
FROM char_test
```

But a better solution would be to declare the column as `varchar2` in the first place so that you don't have the space padding to work around

```
create table varchar_test( column1 varchar2(20) );

insert into varchar_test
WITH cte_test AS 
(
    SELECT '12-3456' AS Column1 from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '78-9101' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1234567-89101' from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-4321' from dual
    )
    select * from cte_test;

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '__-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('000', SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 2))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '___-____' 
            THEN CONCAT('00', SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 3))
        WHEN Column1 LIKE '_______-_____' 
            THEN (SUBSTR(Column1, 3, 5))
        ELSE Column1 
    END AS NewColumn
FROM varchar_test
```

Here is [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f583b2ea92469bb5fd10783aa3067a9) that shows the various options.

Comment: Thank you Justin, due to internal policies I don't have access to the Oracle DB, so I will have my POC see if this solves the issue and get back to you.

Comment: I upvoted your solutions as they worked for me thanks! I don't have 15+ points yet so it isn't reflected but I very much appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle alternative which (in `temp` CTE) extracts the first part of the string (up to the minus sign), and then - depending on its length - left pads it with zeros up to 5 characters in length, or takes the last 5 characters):

```
SQL> WITH cte_test AS
  2  (
  3      SELECT '12-3456' AS Column1 from dual
  4      UNION ALL
  5      SELECT '78-9101' from dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT '1234567-89101' from dual
  8      UNION ALL
  9      SELECT '123-4321' from dual
 10  ),
 11  temp as
 12    (select column1,
 13            substr(column1, 1, instr(column1, '-') - 1) val
 14     from cte_Test
 15    )
 16  select column1,
 17    lpad(case when length(val) < 5 then val
 18              else substr(val, -5)
 19         end, 5, '0'
 20        ) as result
 21  from temp;

COLUMN1       RESULT
------------- --------------------
12-3456       00012
78-9101       00078
1234567-89101 34567
123-4321      00123

SQL>
```

Comment: Can't use REGEX, do you have a solution without it?

Comment: Sure, just modify line #13 to `substr(column1, 1, instr(column1, '-') - 1) val`

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN Column1 LIKE '__-____             '
       THEN '000' || SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 2)
       WHEN Column1 LIKE '___-____            '
       THEN '00' || SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 3)
       WHEN Column1 LIKE '_______-_____       '
       THEN SUBSTR(Column1, 3, 5)
       ELSE Column1
       END AS NewColumn
FROM   schema.table1
```

or:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( Column1, '^\d{2}-\d{4}\s*$' )
       THEN '000' || SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 2)
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( Column1, '^\d{3}-\d{4}\s*$' )
       THEN '00' || SUBSTR(Column1, 1, 3)
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(Column1, '^\d{7}-\d{5}\s*$' )
       THEN SUBSTR(Column1, 3, 5)
       ELSE Column1 
       END AS NewColumn
FROM   schema.table1
```

Or, more simply:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         '000' || SUBSTR(column1, 1, INSTR(column1, '-') - 1),
         -5
       ) AS newcolumn
FROM   schema.table1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE schema.table1( column1 CHAR(20) );

INSERT INTO schema.table1(column1)
SELECT '12-3456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '78-9101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1234567-89101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123-4321' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | NEWCOLUMN |
> | --- |
> | 00012 |
> | 00078 |
> | 34567 |
> | 00123 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8d4971e812d4982a1b292350087eaf5)*

Comment: Can't use REGEX, do you have a solution without it?

Comment: @NicholasGregory Updated with several other solutions.

Comment: Thanks! Job has a convoluted system, I can only query the MSSQL side not the Oracle so I'll get my POC to try this out tomorrow :)